# How can I improve an overlay and modal that displays a spinner during requests?

Tags: html, css

I have a overlay and modal that displays a spinner during long requests using Ajax. But when the loader displays during a request it loses it's `position: fixed;` css attribute. So the user can scroll down and see what lies beneath. How can I prevent that? I have also tried to add a div in between to prevent the user from clicking buttons underneath the overlay while the request is processing, but no success with that either. Any tips on how to improve? Here is the html:

```
<div class="Progress" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal" role="document" tabindex="-1">
        <h3>{% trans 'Please wait...' %}</h3>
        <div id="spinner">
            <div class="lds-css ng-scope">
                <div class="lds-spinner" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and relevant css:

```
.Progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1000;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  float: none;
}

.modal {
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 16px;
  top:40%;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1002;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
h3{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
p{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  margin:0;
}}

#spinner {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  margin:auto;
  float:none;
}
```

If you need additional info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function where you are displaying the spinner and overlay, you can also add a class to the body:

```
.bodyNoScroll {max-height:100vh;overflow:hidden;}
```

Then, when you hide the spinner and overlay, remove that class from the body

```
$('body').removeClass('bodyNoScroll');
```

```js
$('body').addClass('noScroll');
$('#msg, #olay').fadeIn(1500);

$('button').click(function(){
  $('#msg, #olay').fadeOut();
  $('body').removeClass('noScroll');
});
```

```css
#msg, #olay{position:absolute;}
#msg{position:5vh;left:15vh;padding:30px;background:wheat;font-size:1.3rem;z-index:2;display:none;}
#olay{top:0;left:0;width:98vw;height:98vh;background:black;opacity:0.5;z-index:1;display:none;}

.noScroll{max-height:99vh;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg">Spinner!<button>Close</button></div>
<div id="olay"></div>

<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks @gibberish. Implemented and working. Do you have any suggestion for adding a middle layer so that buttons can't be clicked to interrupt the request? I've tried a div between the overlay and modal, but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean (cannot picture the problem)... If you wouldn't mind, please add this question as a new question and be clear about what buttons the user would press that would interrupt ... what? ... Then, please post a comment below this one with the link to the new question. ***Thanks!***

Comment: hopefully this explains it better - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432292/how-to-insert-div-so-that-overlay-and-modal-cannot-be-clicked-through-during-req