# How to insert div so that overlay and modal cannot be clicked through during request?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a overlay and modal that displays a spinner during long requests using Ajax. When the overlay and modal are displayed the user is still able to click on any links or buttons that are on the current page even though they are underneath the overlay, and thereby create a new request to a different page. This isn't a big deal, and most users probably won't do that, but I would like to add a div or something in between the modal or overlay to prevent the user from clicking buttons or links while the request is processing. I tried it, but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Here is the html:

```
<div class="Progress" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="modal" role="document" tabindex="-1">
            <h3>{% trans 'Please wait...' %}</h3>
            <div id="spinner">
                <div class="lds-css ng-scope">
                    <div class="lds-spinner" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and relevant css:

```
.Progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1000;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  float: none;
}

.modal {
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 16px;
  top:40%;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1002;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
h3{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
p{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  margin:0;
}}

#spinner {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  margin:auto;
  float:none;
}
```

If you need additional info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a z-index that raises your overlay above the elements below, then it is not possible for a user to click anything underneath.

In the below demo, the Click Me button (and the poetic text) are at the default z-index value of zero. The full-screen overlay is at z-index 1 and the spinner is at z-index 2.

So, with the overlay taking up the full screen (`top:0;left:0;width:99vw;height:99vh`), and (via z-index) sitting above the click me button, the entire browser window is effectively blocked and nothing below that overlay div can be clicked. *Try it!*

*Note that if the z-indexes on the overlay and spinner div were reversed, then you would not be able to click the close button on the spinner -- and the spinner div would appear dim (because of the background/opacity on the overlay)*

Demo:

```js
$('body').addClass('noScroll');
$('#msg, #olay').fadeIn(1500);

$('button').click(function(){
  $('#msg, #olay').fadeOut();
  $('body').removeClass('noScroll');
});
```

```css
#msg, #olay{position:absolute;}
#msg{position:5vh;left:15vh;padding:30px;background:wheat;font-size:1.3rem;z-index:2;display:none;}
#olay{top:0;left:0;width:98vw;height:98vh;background:black;opacity:0.5;z-index:1;display:none;}

.noScroll{max-height:99vh;overflow:hidden;}

.text-center{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg">Spinner!<button>Close</button></div>
<div id="olay"></div>


<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
<div class="text-center"><button>Click Me</button>
<p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a curious bit of ECMA-script 2017...</p>
```

References:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/